# Angular Mat-form-field placeholder color

Tags: angular, placeholder, mat-form-field

I have a form with an input in a `mat-form-field`. It includes placeholder but I don't know how to set placeholder text color.

When I've not focused previously the input, the placeholder color is grey:

[image]

When input get focused then it turns purple:

[image]

When input lose the focus then it turns red:

[image]

My requirement is to change the purple one. I've tried this solution:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/p/placeholder/
But It didn't work for me.

Any idea?

UPDATED:

This is the inspected input:

```
<input _ngcontent-bqk-c14="" class="inputSearch input-textstyle mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control cdk-text-field-autofill-monitored ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-touched" formcontrolname="description" matinput="" type="text" ng-reflect-autocomplete="[object Object]" ng-reflect-name="description" ng-reflect-placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Buscar" ng-reflect-type="text" autocomplete="off" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-expanded="false" aria-haspopup="true" id="mat-input-1" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Buscar" aria-invalid="true" aria-required="false">
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you have to use `:placeholder` with `:foucs` and `:active`

Comment: It didn't work. I used: input::placeholder:focus:active

Answer (score 0):

In `style.scss` file, place the following style

```
.mat-input-placeholder {
    color: red; /* Any color */
}
```

Please note this will override the Angular Material default style, everywhere.
If you want to apply this in only inside the component, paste the below in `your.component.scss` file

```
::ng-deep .mat-input-placeholder { 
   color: red; /* Any color */
}
```

Comment: I inspected the element, It could be a class that overwrite the style. Added in the question.

Comment: I have applied this same solution in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-form-field-heh77t?file=app/form-field-prefix-suffix-example.css

Comment: Angular material have a seperate label element to denote the placeholder, not from 'input' element.

Comment: From the angular docs:
"Applying the ::ng-deep pseudo-class to any CSS rule completely disables view-encapsulation for that rule. Any style with ::ng-deep applied becomes a global style. In order to scope the specified style to the current component and all its descendants, be sure to include the :host selector before ::ng-deep."

Answer (score 0):

When using the input "placeholder" attribute, you can change the styling with a simple css selector :

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>My label</mat-label>
  <input matInput type="text" placeholder="my placeholder"/>
</mat-form-field>
```

```css
input::placeholder {
  color: green;
}
```

You don't need to use the global stylesheet.
It will not target the default `mat-label` placeholder, it only works with the attribute